# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am currently trying to display an image in tkinter and identify its body using mediapipe. I use Opencv, mediapipe and tkinter for this. I have also implemented something for this, but unfortunately I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the first argument of `mpDraw.draw_landmarks` should be NumPy array, but you are passing and object of type `PhotoImage`.

You may replace `landmarks(photo, results)` with:

```
landmarks(image, results)
```

---

The following code:

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(image))
landmarks(photo, results)
```

Converts `image` from NumPy array to `PhotoImage` object, and passes the object as argument to `landmarks` method (that passes it to `mpDraw.draw_landmarks`).

---

Take a look at the error message:

> if image.shape[2] != RGB_CHANNELS:
> AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'shape'

That means the `image` type is `'PhotoImage'`.
That also implies that `image` must have a `'shape'` attribute, and we some experience we know that NumPy arrays have a `'shape'` attribute.

You may also look at [drawing_utils.py](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/drawing_utils.py).

> Args:
> image: A three channel RGB image represented as numpy ndarray.

---

Note:

- It's hard to tell if there are other errors (it's hard to follow the code).
  My answer address only the posted error messgae.

Comment: Thx. Ive changed it to `landmarks(image, results)`. That was my mistake. I didn't really think about it. As I see it, I need the following for the error message: `if image.shape[2] != RGB_CHANNELS:
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'shape'`, that the Input image must contain three channel rgb data. So I ask myself how I can convert a PhotoImage into three rgb data? Is it possible at all?